# Change input value using javascript

Tags: aura

I have an input in a form built with aura:

```
<input class=" input uiInput uiInputText uiInput--default uiInput--input" type="text" aria-describedby="5284:0" placeholder="" id="7:4790;a" data-aura-rendered-by="17:4790;a" data-aura-class="uiInput uiInputText uiInput--default uiInput--input" data-interactive-lib-uid="54" aria-required="true">
```

I need to change the value of this input using javascript.
However, when doing:

```
document.getElementById("7:4790;a").value = "random value";
```

Visually, it changes the value in the input, but it is not taken into account when saving as if I didn't change anything.

How can I achieve this ?
Do I need to trigger a specific event so that aura takes notice of the new data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your `<input>` element to a `<lightning:input>` or `<ui:input>` component, then add `aura:id="myInputField"` to the component then you can use the following javascript to adjust the value:

```
component.find("myInputField").set("v.value", "random value");
```

As best practice, you should always use `<lightning:input>` or `<ui:input>` components - they're much easier to work within the aura framework